# How do I add search functionality in custom keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

I am creating a **custom keyboard** for android. And I want to add **search functionality** in it.

How do I implement it in keyboard, like the **GBoard** ?

**If this question is a hoax, please let me know.**

[image]

Comment: Are you able to get it done, i need to know some facts regarding it. could u plz help

Comment: Hey @AshishAgrawal, I was busy with my exams, once I'm done with them, I'll let you know what happens.